# Android Studio library modules cant generate R.java

Tags: android

I write a library module that other module can depend on.
I create a library module and write some code in it.
This is a Custom View. I create attr.xml like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="top_icon" format="reference" />
    <attr name="bottom_icon" format="reference" />

    <declare-styleable name="GradientIconView">
        <attr name="top_icon" />
        <attr name="bottom_icon" />
    </declare-styleable>

    <attr name="text" format="string" />
    <attr name="text_size" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="top_text_color" format="color" />
    <attr name="bottom_text_color" format="color" />

    <declare-styleable name="GradientTextView">
        <attr name="text" />
        <attr name="text_size" />
        <attr name="top_text_color" />
        <attr name="bottom_text_color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I write some code like this.

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.GradientIconView);

    BitmapDrawable drawable;

    int n = a.getIndexCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        int attr = a.getIndex(i);
        switch (attr) {
            case R.styleable.GradientIconView_top_icon:
                drawable = (BitmapDrawable) a.getDrawable(attr);
                setTopIconView(drawable);
                break;
            case R.styleable.GradientIconView_bottom_icon:
                drawable = (BitmapDrawable) a.getDrawable(attr);
                setBottomIconView(drawable);
                break;

        }
    }
```

It says cannot resolve symbol 'R', i rebuild the project and make the library module. It doesnt work.
Here is the project structure.
[image: Structure about project]

Comment: At first the project has no library module, I create the Custom View in app module and it work well. Then i want to make the Custom View in library module, it has problem.

Comment: Clean and Rebuild project :)

Comment: @Michele It does not work.

Comment: Maybe a syntax error in one of the xml files?

Comment: I solve it by my self. As of ADT 14, resource constants in library projects are no longer final. You can see my answer. @Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find what the problem is. It's not the R.java not generated. It just the R.styleable.*** cannot be used in a switch statement in Android library modules.

As of ADT 14, resource constants in library projects are no longer final.
So i change my code like this. It work well.

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.GradientIconView);

    BitmapDrawable drawable;

    int n = a.getIndexCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        int attr = a.getIndex(i);
        if (attr == R.styleable.GradientIconView_top_icon) {
            drawable = (BitmapDrawable) a.getDrawable(attr);
            setTopIconView(drawable);
            break;
        }
        else if(attr == R.styleable.GradientIconView_bottom_icon) {
                drawable = (BitmapDrawable) a.getDrawable(attr);
                setBottomIconView(drawable);
                break;
        }
    }

    a.recycle();
```

Finally, i solve it by myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
-Delete folder YourApp/build, YourApp/app/build and all file .iml
-Restart android studio and clean-rebuild
Hope It help you

Comment: Do as you said, I can't load my project now.

Comment: why can't? You can do this by using explore( not use android studio)

Comment: I recover it by import this project again: )  I found it that R.id.XXX is generated but R.styleable.XXX is not. This is the problem is.

Comment: Do you try rename attr file to attrs? Can you find R.styleable.GradientIconView ?

Comment: The problem is not about i can't find R.styleable.GradientIconView, It's about we can't use R.styleable.GradientIconView in switch case statement since API 14,  You can see my answer:) @Phan Sinh

Comment: after restarting you should import your project not opening it